# Sending Application Key via SendKeys.Send

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an app that lets you navigate between items using SendKeys. All works pretty well except when I try to send the Application Key (context menu) to do a right click on the selected item. 
I use:

```
SendKeys.Send("{APPSKEY}");
```

I get an Error saying 'Keyword "APPSKEY" is not valid.'

I googled it and found it on this website: 
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm 
But i'm guessing that doesn't work for c#.

is there any other way to do a rightclick on the selected item? 
is there a way to tell the app where the item is located to move the mouse there and do a right click?

my program can send MouseClicks:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention =
CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint 
    cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    private void MoveCursor(Point loc)
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = loc;
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private void DoMouseClick(bool isLeft)
    {
        int X = Cursor.Position.X;
        int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
        if (isLeft) mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (uint)X, (uint)Y, 0, 0);
        else mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, (uint)X, (uint)Y, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

But in order to simulate a right click on that item the app has to know where it is located.

Comment: In general we don't add tags to the title, that is where tags are for.

Comment: The SendKeys class was intended to help port VB6 applications.  15 years ago keyboards didn't yet have this key.  The Windows key is awol too.  You'll need to pinvoke SendInput().

Comment: Looks like that your first step is to **find the focused/selected item** on your form?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SendKeys.Send("+{F10}");
```

Regards,